# SQL Server 2014 - How to find the Min Date between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

OK People. I'm only new at writing these queries so go easy on me...
I want to find the Min Date between 2 fields, I worked out how to do this for a SUM but not MIN (apparently + doesn't work for min...) 
As you will see from the below, the first line (the line in **) is not correct (I know that there should not be a , but i have given up). The next line is perfection and is exactly what i'm trying to achieve the with MIN code...
Basically i have 2 tables (ScanLine and Inventory) I am trying to get the Min ProductionDate from both of these tables, on the same line...

** I dont want to use Aliases for the joins and i would like to avoid using UNION if possible **

```
SELECT (SELECT min(inventory.productiondate)),
       (SELECT min(scanline.productiondate)) AS OldDate,
       (SELECT sum(Inventory.NetWeight)) + (SELECT sum(scanline.weight)) AS Wgt,
       sum(inventory.units) AS Qty,
       count(inventory.palletbarcode) AS Pallets
FROM   scowms.inventory
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       scowms.scanline
       ON scowms.inventory.barcode = scowms.scanline.barcode
WHERE  inventory.locationbarcode = '2D03D';
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: If you just want an independent minimum value from both tables you don't need to join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` to get the minimum from the two columns:

```
select (case when min(i.productiondate) < min(s.productiondate)
             then min(i.productiondate)
             else coalesce(min(s.productiondate), min(i.productiondate))
        end)
from scowms.inventory i left join
     scowms.scanline s
     on i.barcode = s.barcode
where i.locationbarcode = '2D03D';
```

Table aliases are a good thing.  They make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Gordon Linoff as I unerstand from the question he has asked for both the minimum date as 2 columns "Min ProductionDate from both of these tables, on the same line..." . Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @HardikParmar . . . In the context, I interpreted that as "Min ProductionDate from both of these tables, in the same column".  That might not be accurate, but the provided query has the two values in two different columns.